# Angular 6 Meta service with dynamic metadata from web service

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata, angular-universal, angular7

I'm trying to use data retrieved from a web service to update the metadata in an Angular 6 (update: now Angular 7) Universal app (using Meta and Title). I'm specifically doing this for Twitter and Facebook cards. I know that their crawlers don't execute JavaScript which is why I use Angular Universal to set the metadata on the server side. I'm using the [Facebook Sharing debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the results.

I've tried a few different approaches, and I've looked for examples, but I haven't found one where data is retrieved from an async call to a web service before the metadata is set. (Note that I used this service successfully with a web service in an Angular Universal 4 app.)

Using the code below, the "og:url" tag is properly set as that one does not require the web service call to get the data. However, the title is not properly being set. If I move the "setTitle" call to ngOnInit and supply a string, that works--but getting the data from the web service doesn't.

I've tried using a service to collect the data and then set the metadata, but that isn't working either. I get the data from the resolver but it doesn't solve the Facebook/Twitter problem.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const metaUrl = 'https://www.test.com' + this._router.url;
    this._metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: metaUrl });

    this._sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const code = params['person'];
      this.getInfo(code);
    });
}

getInfo(code: string) {
  this._myWebService.getPerson(code).subscribe(
      data => {
        this._person = data;
        // set dynamic metadata
        const metaTitle = this._person.name + ' | site description';
        this._titleService.setTitle(metaTitle);
        this._metaService.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: metaTitle });
  });

}
```

Update: I also tried using a Resolver to get the data first so that I could just use it in onInit. It's not working.

```
 { path: 'view/:person', component: ViewComponent,
    resolve: { person: ViewResolver }, data: { person: ViewResolver }
  }
```

Then in onInit:

```
const data: any = this._routeActive.snapshot.data;
this.metaTitle = data.person.value.name;
this._metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:title', content: this.metaTitle });
this._metaService.updateTag({name: 'twitter:title', content: this.metaTitle });
```

Comment: Did you check that the code execution does go though `getInfo` server side?

Comment: Yes, I checked the server rendered page and everything is fine including the meta tags in the source. However, when I deploy the app to Google App Engine, The Facebook debug tool does not see the updated meta tags. I’ve even added a resolver to get the data first and it’s still not working.

Comment: Something must be wrong with Angular Universal, as the code supplied looks OK. AU stops the rendering when there is no more things to do in the ngZone, maybe the API call runs outside ngZone? Could it be a connection issue? Maybe the API call's observable returns with an error, which could provide more info. Does the AU server work locally? You can check the output string quite easily on you local machine. :thinking: :thinking:

Comment: I agree with your assessment. I’ve checked locally and the server-side page is correct (ie the correct tags are in the source). Any suggestion for how to debug this on the prod environment? Maybe I should set the SSR page to a different port and check it that way? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to create a service, which is injected as dependency to SSR application. So that you first create and fill in that service completely server-side, and then pass all the data to `render` of SSR application. It is hard to control asynchronous calls while rendering, so we found that good practice is resolve all the data in advance, and pass it `render` for as less as possible extra jobs. I can show you example if still interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. After deciding this must not be a code issue, I went to the [Angular Universal starter repo](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) and updated my config (e.g., tsconfig.json, angular.json, etc.) until it worked. My project has been upgraded a few times and I hadn't copied over all the changes from the starter repo.